# Inserir Função Apenas Se Não Existir

Tags: javascript

A função "window.showModalDialog" existe em algumas versões de IE, porém não existe no Chrome, gostaria de inseri-la se ela não existir. Como posso fazer isso?

```
window.showModalDialog = function (arg1, arg2, arg3) { 
//Minha função
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa funcionalidade [não é uniformizada, está deprecada, e deve ser evitada](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog).

Acho que colocas questões diferentes aqui, e interessantes de separar.

#### Como/quando aplicar um polyfill

Podes detetar se a função existe e caso não exista aplicar uma função tua com comportamento semelhante. Algo como:

```
if (!window.showModalDialog) window.showModalDialog = function(){
    // etc ...
```

#### Como reproduzir essa funcionalidade (ie como criar um polyfill para este método)?

Isso existe já e podes encontrar no Github aqui: https://github.com/niutech/showModalDialog

A MDN [também aponta](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog#See_also) para esse repositório que tem [uma demo aqui](http://niutech.github.io/showModalDialog/demo.html).